# Possible to disable an SQL execution plan in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have a situation where Oracle creates multiple execution plans for a given query. Most of the time, it chooses a certain one that performs quite well. Sometimes, however, it chooses one that contains a cartesian join which is very wrong. If we delete the cartesian join plan and run the query with one of the others plans, it performs well, which suggests to me that the underlying data truly did not need the cartesian.

We've tried gathering stats and fiddling with histograms but it seems, eventually, the cartesian join execution plan comes back and is intermittently used (sometimes this takes weeks or months).

Is it possible in Oracle to disable a specific execution plan? We can't just delete it because it seems to come back, but leaving it there and having it disabled should serve as a fix, but I don't really know how to do that or if it is possible.

Comment: Look into SQL Profiles.

Comment: Or baselines, as explained in my answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41858149/how-to-force-accept-a-sql-plan-baseline]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, using SQL Plan Baselines is the official way to disable an execution plan.  It works but it is incredibly painful as the below code demonstrates.

---

Create a bad plan by creating the objects and gathering stats *before* loading the data.

```
drop table bad_index;
create table bad_index(a number, b number);
create index bad_index on bad_index(a);
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'bad_index');
end;
/
insert into bad_index select level, level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;
```

The query plan is wrong.  It thinks there is only one row when the query will really return 100,000 rows.  It uses a NESTED LOOPS when it should use a HASH JOIN instead.

```
explain plan for
select count(*)
from bad_index bi1, bad_index bi2
where bi1.a = bi2.a
    and bi1.a > 0;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 4168051245

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |     1 |    26 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |           |     1 |    26 |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS     |           |     1 |    26 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| BAD_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| BAD_INDEX |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("BI1"."A">0)
   4 - access("BI1"."A"="BI2"."A")
       filter("BI2"."A">0)
```

Run the above query without the `explain plan for` to generate a real SQL_ID.  Then find the SQL_ID (5ukbyc726cdu3).

```
select *
from gv$sql
where sql_text like '%bad_index bi1%'
    and sql_text not like '%quine%'
    and sql_text not like '%explain%';
```

Use that SQL_ID to create a SQL Plan Baseline to capture information about the query.

```
declare
    v_result pls_integer;
begin
    v_result := dbms_spm.load_plans_from_cursor_cache(sql_id => '5ukbyc726cdu3');
end;
/
```

You can see the SQL Plan Baseline here.  Right now it only has one plan:

```
select * from dba_sql_plan_baselines;
```

Let's generate a better plan by gathering stats and re-running.

```
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'bad_index');
end;
/

select count(*)
from bad_index bi1, bad_index bi2
where bi1.a = bi2.a
    and bi1.a > 0;
```

But wait, that new plan isn't working yet.  Note that the bad plan is still in use.  Pay attention to the `Note` section - it is using a SQL plan baseline.

```
explain plan for
select count(*)
from bad_index bi1, bad_index bi2
where bi1.a = bi2.a
    and bi1.a > 0;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 4168051245

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |           |     1 |    10 |   100K  (1)| 00:00:04 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |           |     1 |    10 |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS     |           |   100K|   976K|   100K  (1)| 00:00:04 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| BAD_INDEX |   100K|   488K|   201   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN| BAD_INDEX |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("BI1"."A">0)
   4 - access("BI1"."A"="BI2"."A")
       filter("BI2"."A">0)

Note
-----
   - SQL plan baseline "SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq561d678a6" used for this statement
```

Now there are two plans for the SQL plan baseline.  The first one is accepted and the newer, better plan is not.

```
select sql_handle, plan_name, origin, enabled, accepted, fixed from dba_sql_plan_baselines order by origin desc;

SQL_HANDLE             PLAN_NAME                        ORIGIN                          ENABLED   ACCEPTED   FIXED
SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5   SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq561d678a6   MANUAL-LOAD-FROM-CURSOR-CACHE   YES       YES        NO
SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5   SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq52b66d432   AUTO-CAPTURE                    YES       NO         NO
```

Evolve the plan to potentially accept the new plan.  The exact output of the function doesn't matter here but you can look at it if you're curious.

```
declare
    v_clob clob;
begin
    v_clob := dbms_spm.evolve_sql_plan_baseline(sql_handle => 'SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5');
    dbms_output.put_line(v_clob);
end;
/
```

Take another look at the baselines and they are both accepted.

```
select sql_handle, plan_name, origin, enabled, accepted, fixed from dba_sql_plan_baselines order by origin desc;

SQL_HANDLE             PLAN_NAME                        ORIGIN                          ENABLED   ACCEPTED   FIXED
SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5   SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq561d678a6   MANUAL-LOAD-FROM-CURSOR-CACHE   YES       YES        NO
SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5   SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq52b66d432   AUTO-CAPTURE                    YES       YES        NO
```

Set ENABLED to NO for the old plan and set it to YES for the new plan.  This isn't necessary if the new plan is better, but this will ensure the old plan is never used.

```
declare
    v_result pls_integer;
begin
    v_result := dbms_spm.alter_sql_plan_baseline(sql_handle => 'SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5', plan_name => 'SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq561d678a6', attribute_name => 'ENABLED', attribute_value => 'NO');
    v_result := dbms_spm.alter_sql_plan_baseline(sql_handle => 'SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5', plan_name => 'SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq52b66d432', attribute_name => 'ENABLED', attribute_value => 'YES');
end;
/
```

Verify that the old plan is no longer enabled.

```
select sql_handle, plan_name, origin, enabled, accepted, fixed from dba_sql_plan_baselines order by origin desc;

SQL_HANDLE             PLAN_NAME                        ORIGIN                          ENABLED   ACCEPTED   FIXED
SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5   SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq561d678a6   MANUAL-LOAD-FROM-CURSOR-CACHE   NO        YES        NO
SQL_e6b3513bd71cbec5   SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq52b66d432   AUTO-CAPTURE                    YES       YES        NO
```

Now the query will only use the newer, better plan with `Rows` set to 100K and using HASH JOIN instead of NESTED LOOPs.

```
explain plan for
select count(*)
from bad_index bi1, bad_index bi2
where bi1.a = bi2.a
    and bi1.a > 0;

select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 544904072

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |           |     1 |    10 |       |   278   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE        |           |     1 |    10 |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN            |           |   100K|   976K|  1664K|   278   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| BAD_INDEX |   100K|   488K|       |    57   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| BAD_INDEX |   100K|   488K|       |    57   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("BI1"."A"="BI2"."A")
   3 - filter("BI1"."A">0)
   4 - filter("BI2"."A">0)

Note
-----
   - SQL plan baseline "SQL_PLAN_fdcuj7gbjtgq52b66d432" used for this statement
```

### Congratulations if you've made it this far

The above code is horrible.  Oracle really dropped the ball with this system but this is the "official" way to do it.

It's usually better to avoid SQL plan baselines and find some other solution.  Find out what is causing the bad execution plan and stop it.

Comment: Very thorough answer. I want to clarify one thing though: I'd have to get a bad plan accepted as a baseline before I could disable it, is that correct? If, as in my situation, a bad execution plan suddenly appeared after months of using a good plan, would it be possible to mark it as a baseline to then disable it?